# Contao 4 Pagebuilder Module?

Tags: contao

I just started a new project on Contao 4 CMS and are a bit stunned by the absense of an easy "editor friendly" way to edit and manipulate the content.

Is there some kind of custom module which adds this "pagebuilder" feature as we know it from other cms systems like Wordpress or Drupal (with Paragraphs module)?

Comment: It's contao 4.4 currently, but 4.9 out of the box seems to be the same in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Contao (all versions) the actual content of pages (i.e. page articles), news articles, events etc. is represented by so called "content elements". You do not need to enable anything in order to be able to create and edit content elements (assuming you have an administrator account - because editing can be restricted for non-admins, depending on the settings). See [the manual](https://docs.contao.org/manual/en/article-management/content-elements/) to get an overview over content elements in general and which content element types are available by default.

Btw. you need to make sure that the "Articles" module is enabled for at least one section of your layout in your [page layout's](https://docs.contao.org/manual/en/layout/theme-manager/manage-page-layouts/) settings, in order to be able to create page articles and edit their content.

See also the [Create the first start page](https://docs.contao.org/manual/en/guides/add-first-index-page/) article in the manual.

Comment: Thx a lot for this short overview! So I guess content editors have to learn this system instead of better usability?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What is a "system of better usability"?

Comment: It's probably more pilosophical and does not really belong here on SO, but at the moment contao pages have first this articles, and then the articles have this small components in it. There is no real way to see what you are editing without clicking like crazy back and force with quite some guessing on top. I was just wondering, wether there is a way to have it clearly visible which element belongs to which content without this overhead.

Comment: But you can clearly see it? You see which content elements belong to which article and which articles belong to which page. Further more you can click the page's icon (or click on "Preview" in the top menu) in order to see a preview of the page.

Comment: And to be honest, I find Contao's content element concept far superior to Drupal's Paragraphs, the latter of which is not even part of Drupal's core. And WordPress' approach to managing content is also controversial. In the end it just depends on what tool (i.e. CMS) fits best to your needs or with which tool you can work the best.

Comment: Absolutely agreed on the part of that different tools are made for different purposes - I also think I'm a bit too dramatic here - it's a contao legacy project and feels like somebody did not know how to use custom content elements and stuff and has rebuild it manually using the markup element... (including custom css as style tag). Eventually I'll clean it up and probably by that time I like contao already ;)

Comment: And many thx for your patient support in answering my beginners questions!